# Combine rows in the table. Postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I have a table:

```
CREATE TABLE sale_tender_t0
(
  sten_bill bigint NOT NULL,
  sten_paymentform smallint NOT NULL,
  sten_tenderamount integer,
  sten_changeamount integer,
  sten_isfiscal character(1),
  sten_accid integer,
  sten_id bigserial NOT NULL,
  sten_map_user integer,
  sten_storeid integer NOT NULL
```

and some data, like:

```
11246276310734;0;5000;2748;"0";;1913;;1
11246277847093;0;25000;2083;"0";;1914;;1
11246280935156;0;2254;0;"0";;1915;;1
11246281048531;0;2240;100;"0";;1916;;1
11246281345250;0;10000;1360;"0";;1917;;1
```

`sten_bill` - should have unique data, but sometimes happens the data sten_bill is duplicated.
using this script i can find duplicated data:

```
select sten_bill from sale_tender_t0 GROUP by sten_bill
HAVING count(*)>1;
```

But i need to fix the table, for example:

```
11246276310734;0;5000;2748;"0";;1913;;1
11246276310734;1;5000;2748;"0";;1913;;1
```

should fix like:

```
11246276310734;1;10000;5496;"0";;1913;;1
```

Delete first column, and change second column data `column2.sten_tenderamount + column1.sten_tenderamount` and `column2.sten_changeamount + column2.sten_changeamount`

Comment: You need some kind of a unique identifier A.K.A. `primary key` in order to distinguish somehow the rows.

Comment: Unrelated, but: it's cleaner to use a real `boolean` for a flag like `sten_isfiscal`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
WITH max_id_and_summed_amounts AS (
  SELECT
    sten_bill,
    SUM(sten_tenderamount) AS sten_tenderamount,
    SUM(sten_changeamount) AS sten_changeamount,
    MAX(sten_id) AS sten_id
  FROM
    sale_tender_t0
  GROUP BY
    sten_bill
  HAVING
    COUNT(*)>1
),
newest_line AS (
  SELECT
    miasa.sten_bill,
    stt.sten_paymentform,
    miasa.sten_tenderamount,
    miasa.sten_changeamount,
    stt.sten_isfiscal,
    stt.sten_accid,
    miasa.sten_id,
    stt.sten_map_user,
    stt.sten_storeid
  FROM
    max_id_and_summed_amounts miasa INNER JOIN sale_tender_t0 stt
  ON
    miasa.sten_id=stt.sten_id
),
deleted_rows AS (
  DELETE FROM
    sale_tender_t0
  WHERE
    sten_bill IN (
      SELECT
        sten_bill
      FROM
        max_id_and_summed_amounts
    )
)
INSERT INTO
  sale_tender_t0
SELECT
  *
FROM
  newest_line;
```

**Edit**: PostgreSQL versions 8.4 and older do not support [Common Table Expressions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html), so you need to use temporary tables instead.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE max_id_and_summed_amounts
  AS
SELECT
  sten_bill,
  SUM(sten_tenderamount) AS sten_tenderamount,
  SUM(sten_changeamount) AS sten_changeamount,
  MAX(sten_id) AS sten_id
FROM
  sale_tender_t0
GROUP BY
  sten_bill
HAVING
  COUNT(*)>1;

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE newest_line
  AS
SELECT
  miasa.sten_bill,
  stt.sten_paymentform,
  miasa.sten_tenderamount,
  miasa.sten_changeamount,
  stt.sten_isfiscal,
  stt.sten_accid,
  miasa.sten_id,
  stt.sten_map_user,
  stt.sten_storeid
FROM
  max_id_and_summed_amounts miasa INNER JOIN sale_tender_t0 stt
ON
  miasa.sten_id=stt.sten_id;

DELETE FROM
  sale_tender_t0
WHERE
  sten_bill IN (
    SELECT
      sten_bill
    FROM
      max_id_and_summed_amounts
  );

INSERT INTO
  sale_tender_t0
SELECT
  *
FROM
  newest_line;

DROP TABLE max_id_and_summed_amounts;
DROP TABLE newest_line;
```

Comment: You could add a `returning *` to the final `select` in order to see the rows that were aggregated.

Comment: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "DELETE"
LINE 20:   DELETE FROM

Comment: Just discovered the same issue, thanks horse, I edited the answer accordingly. Otherwise it was complaining for a `missing FROM-clause entry for table "duplicate_rows"`

Comment: Perhaps you are using a version of PostgreSQL that does not support Common Table Expressions, such as 8.4 or older?

Comment: Is it possible to alter on Postgres 8.4 ?

Comment: I've just included a solution for PostgreSQL 8.4. as well.

Comment: Great, but one more issue sten_paymentform should be not max, bat same as in newest line
or sten_paymentform should be from line where sten_id is max

Comment: Define `newest line` please?

Comment: for
`11246276310734;  0  ;5000;2748;"0";;1913;;1
11246276310734;  1  ;5000;2748;"0";;1914;;1`
result is good, but if i have
11246276310734;  1  ;5000;2748;"0";;1913;;1
11246276310734;  0  ;5000;2748;"0";;1914;;1
result shound be:
11246276310734;  0  ;10000;5496;"0";;1914;;1

Comment: I understand what you mean, but how would you describe the `newest line` to the database? What is the ordering criteria?

Comment: use sten_id - it is uniqe value, the line i need always hase bigger value

Comment: Then you need a second pass over the `sale_tender_t0` in order to obtain the value of `sten_paymentform`, corresponding to the max `sten_id`. I edited the answer. Better make the `sten_id` a `primary key` (`bigserial` is not guaranteeing uniqueness, nor is creating an index on it).